# Removing Comments Timestamp and order status from Order PDF

Tags: magento-1.9

> I have a client who has the comments history printed on his order pdf.
>   I think we use Fooman Print order?
>
> He uses this to pass on information to couriers like "please leave at
>   back door" however with the full-time stamp and order status on it
>   this often splits over 2 lines.
>
> For example, we are talking about this line from comment history which
>   is on our pdf:
>
> 11/10/2017 | Pending Payment Comment by customer: Please leave at back
>   door
>
> Is there a way to either REMOVE the timestamp | Order Status (
>   11/10/2017 | Pending Payment Comment by customer:)  or put a LINE
>   BREAK after "Comment by customer" so the comment itself appears on its
>   own line?
>
> Thanks for your help Denise

Comment: to be honnest Denise you can best ask Fooman. I worked with him before and he is a nice guy that will help you out

Comment: There is a way, but you would have to get familiar with the code of the extension (or find someone who is). Maybe if you could find the responsible file, someone here could help you